# Problem executing python predictor node in KNIME for SARIMA model

Tags: python, time-series, arima, knime

Im performing time series analysis and KNIME doesnt seem to provide the SARIMA node.
Hence i integrated knime with python to use python to explicitly code the SARIMA model and forecast. 
I have been able to fit the model in python learner node but i cant seem to code the python predictor node. any help would be great.
Below is the code i have used to configure python learner node.

```
from numpy import array, ones, linalg
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Only use numeric columns
data = input_table._get_numeric_data()

mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data, trend='n', order=(0,1,0), seasonal_order=(1,1,1,12))
results = mod.fit()
print(results.summary())
output_model = results
```

A code for both nodes , learner and predictor node would be the best help, but any kind of help is welcomed right now.

Comment: Do you mean seasonal ARIMA? As I [remember](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.arima.node.parameter.importer.ARIMAParameterImporterNodeFactory) the nodes support seasonal ARIMA, only the learner was not reliable enough to support it, but if you import a seasonal ARIMA model, the rest should work as expected.

Comment: @GáborBakos yes, the Arima learner doesn't support SARIMA model. my question is
1. how do i import a sarima model?
2. how do i pass it to the learner?

Comment: The importer linked before describes the table format, it expects for the model. The learner is not needed, predictor and the visualizer are enough to work with.

Comment: @GáborBakos Thank you so much sir, you just helped me get out of something i was stuck on for quite  a while now. Is there anyway i can connect with you if i need any further help? Linkedin?

Comment: @GáborBakos ive given the model to importer node and then to the predictor. but how do i find out the ar1 and ma1 etc values?

Comment: I am not familiar with the python models, but they should contain these values - assuming they work similarly to the R models (KNIME's model was modelled based on the R model).